# Import .csv file into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, bigdata, nosql

I am trying to Import data from csv file to mongodb

CSV file having bellow data

7259555112 774561213 3   4

7259555112 774561214 4   5

7259555112 774561215 1   3

7259555112 774561216 2   1

7259555112 774561217 4   2

7259555112 774561218 6   1

7975795117 7599702622 3  2

7975795117 7599702623 2  1

Where first Number is MISDIN(cell_number), 
      secod Number is MISDIN
      Third field is how mnay incomings first MISDIN got from second 
      Fourth fiels is how many outgoings from first to second

I want to import this to mongodb, where I am in need of collection
schema as bellow

7259555112 (first_doucment I want to make first Misdin as index)

{

{MSISDN:774561213

incoming_count:4

outgoing_count:3

total_count:7

is_EE:1

},

{MSISDN:774561214

incoming_count:3

outgoing_count:2

total_count:5

is_EE:1

},

{MSISDN:774561215

incoming_count:1

outgoing_count:2

total_count:3

is_EE:0

}

}

7975795117(second document)

{

{MSISDN:7599702622

incoming_count:3

outgoing_count:2

total_count:5

is_EE:1

},

{MSISDN:7599702623

incoming_count:2

outgoing_count:1

total_count:3

is_EE:1

},

Please guide how to achive this, using mongoimport or anyother tool

Thanks

Comment: What problems are you having with the command line tool, `mongoimport`?

Comment: With mongoimport you can specify either to look in the file for a header line that describes the fields you are importing, or a separate file with the field descriptions. Check the help

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you want a document for each unique MISDIN in the first column, with each document having a subdocument for each MISDIN in the second column with which the first MISDIN has incoming/outgoing calls. So, for the data you provided, a document in the collection would look like this:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5237258211f41a0c647c47b1"),
  MISDIN_mine: 7259555112,
  call_records: [
  { MISDIN_theirs: 774561213,
    incoming_count: 3,
    outgoing_count: 4,
    total_count: 7,
    is_EE: 1
  }, 
  { MISDIN_theirs: 774561214,
    incoming_count: 4,
    outgoing_count: 5,
    total_count: 9,
    is_EE: 1
  } 
  ... ]
}
```

Admittedly, I'm not sure what `is_EE` is supposed to represent, but let's get the rest into place.

In order to import the data in the format you want, first add a header (a line at the top) to your CSV file that looks like this:

```
MISDIN_mine,MISDIN_theirs,incoming_count,outgoing_count
7259555112,774561213,3,4
7259555112,774561214,4,5
...
```

And run a mongoimport as follows:

```
mongoimport --db yourdb --collection celldata --type csv --file path/to/file.csv --headerline
```

Right now, if you look in the celldata collection, you'll note that the documents actually look like this:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5237258211f41a0c647c47b1"),
  MISDIN_mine: 7259555112,
  MISDIN_theirs: 774561213,
  incoming_count: 3,
  outgoing_count: 4
}
```

The next step is to add the total count field to the subdocument. (Though, to be honest, if you can just pop your csv file open in Excel or a similar program and do the calculation there, adding another column for total_count, that may be easier for you.) Otherwise, you can use the [cursor.forEach()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/).

```
db.celldata.find().forEach(function(myDoc) { db.cell.update({_id:myDoc._id},{$set:{"total_count":myDoc.incoming_count+myDoc.outgoing_count}})});
```

Now, your documents should look like this:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5237258211f41a0c647c47b1"),
  MISDIN_mine: 7259555112,
  MISDIN_theirs: 774561213,
  incoming_count: 3,
  outgoing_count: 4,
  total_count: 7
}
```

You can now add in the is_EE field. Now, on to turning these documents into subdocuments! We're going to use aggregation, specifically the [group command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/group/), to

```
var reduce = function(curr, result) {
  result.call_records.push(
    { 
      MISDIN_theirs: curr.MISDIN_theirs,
      incoming_count: curr.incoming_count,
      outgoing_count: curr.outgoing_count,
      total_count: curr.total_count,
      is_EE: curr.is_EE          
    }); 
};

db.new_celldata.insert(db.celldata.group({key: {"MISDIN_mine": 1}, reduce: reduce, initial: {call_records:[]}}))
```

Now we have a collection, new_celldata, where the data looks like we want it to! Finally, the last step is to create an index on MISDIN_mine.

```
db.new_celldata.ensureIndex({MISDIN_mine: 1});
```

Now, you can use the new_celldata collection to solve whatever problem you're working on. :)